# how to use ember 2.0 with ember starter kit?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to use [the recent release of ember-2.0.0](http://emberjs.com/builds/#/release) with [the ember starter kit](http://github.com/emberjs/starter-kit). The only change I've made is to upgrade the versions of the included ember as well as the 2.0.0 version of the template-compiler. The index.html page renders with no errors, no deprecation warnings, and no index template.

Has support for templates defined in script tags been removed? Or the syntax changed?

Here is [my fork with the above changes](https://github.com/robcmills/starter-kit)

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but why not use Ember CLI?

Comment: I use Ember CLI for ambitious web apps. For learning, debugging, experimenting, and playing around with isolated components I prefer a pared down, minimal environment that doesn't have a vast tree of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The index template was in fact rendering, but the syntax for the handlebars `{{#each` helper has changed:

`javascript
  {{#each model as |item|}}
    <li>{{item}}</li>
  {{/each}}`